# Prompt video file for download over http instead of initating stream

Tags: http, video, browser, mobile, download

I'm trying to setup a download page for some video files to mobile devices.

Ideally, I'd like it if I click or navigate to a download link, I'm prompted to download the file (or the file automatically downloads).

Currently, I navigate from my mobile device to:

```
192.168.1.4/Star.avi
```

And the video starts playing.

Is there anything I can do server side to prevent this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the header field below:

Content-Disposition: attachment

Comment: Where do I add this header field?>

Comment: I found the answer here: http://www.jtricks.com/howto/content_disposition/apache2.html

I tried it on my device and it works!

Thanks!